# How to validate angular form when button clicks

Tags: angular

> I need to validate form when a user clicks on the submit button. How
> to do it?

```
this.userForm = new FormGroup({
      Name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      Gender: new FormControl('M', Validators.required),
      Address: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please try this!

```
buttonClicks(){
  if(this.userForm.valid()){
    //Valid form 
  } else{
    //Invalid form
    this.userForm.markAllAsTouched();
  }
}
```